# Sending Audio file from Django to Vue

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

I'm trying to send gtts generated audio file from Django to Vue via HttpResponse.

Django's views.py:

```
f = open('path/of/mp3/file', 'rb')
response = HttpResponse()
response.write(f.read())
response['Content-Type'] = 'audio/mp3'
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize('path/of/mp3/file')

return response
```

and when vue receives the response data, it is like the below:

```
data: '��D�\x00\x11C\x19�\x01F(\x00\x00\x04 �&N�""""���ޓ�������\x7F���B\x10���w�����…���_�F��1B��H���\x16LAME3.100�����������������������' # and so on
```

I guess it is because the bytes have been converted to string over the transfer and I have to convert it back to the audio file. But no matter whether using blob or other suggested methods, I could not convert it to an mp3 file to be played in javascript.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to play audio in the browser, so it really depends on how you mean to play your audio file.

#### creating `<audio>` element

```js
const el = document.createElement('audio');
el.src = `${API_URL}/file.mp3`;
el.play();
```

#### using `Audio()` constructor

```js
new Audio(`${API_URL}/file.mp3`).play();
```

#### converting binary data (Axios)

```js
const context = new AudioContext();

axios
  .get(`${API_URL}/file.mp3`, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  })
  .then(res => {
    context.decodeAudioData(res.data).then(buffer => {
      const source = context.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = buffer;
      source.connect(context.destination);
      source.start();
    });
  });
```

#### converting binary data (Fetch API)

```js
const context = new AudioContext();

fetch(`${API_URL}/file.mp3`).then(res => {
  res.arrayBuffer().then(arrayBuffer => {
    context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer).then(buffer => {
      const source = context.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = buffer;
      source.connect(context.destination);
      source.start();
    });
  });
});
```

Hopefully one of these methods helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it weeks ago thanks to the above answer but posting what has solved my problem for future reference.
My problem was not setting up a responseType for axios after all...

the below code solved my problem:

```
axios.post(DJANGO_PORT_ADDRSS, formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    responseType: 'blob', // this solved my problem
    onUploadProgress: ({loaded, total}) => {
      // process loading percentage
      if (loaded == total) {
        // show 100%
      }
    }
  }).then( res => {
    this.sound = res.data;
  }).catch(console.error);
}
```

and then I created "new Blob([sound], {type: 'audio/mp3'})" to play the sound